# What is the term for the procedure used to delay an arraignment?

Tags: criminal-law, georgia

If a lawyer wants to delay an arraignment after a date has been set, what do they do?

Comment: Request a continuance?

Comment: @bdb484 Is that a motion that the lawyer would file with the judge?

Comment: How is this asking for legal advice?!  It is a generic question about a procedure, and the term for that procedure.  (*minor* edit made, voting to reopen...)

Comment: @MichaelHall Yes, the close votes are really getting out of hand.

Comment: I've raised the issue at Meta: https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1872/are-we-perhaps-going-overboard-with-the-rsla-closures/1873#1873

Comment: @Paul59 Yes. Technically, the motion would probably be filed with the clerk of courts, who would forward it on to the judge.